# The longest Ablative Absolute construction attested in the Latin literature?

Tags: syntax, ablative-absolute

I was curious about the longest Ablative Absolute (AA) construction **attested** in the Latin literature. For example, the following one from Plautus has seven AAs juxtaposed (used by him to create a comic effect). Have you ever found any candidates that break this record?

> Hostibus victis, civibus salvis, re placida, pacibus perfectis, bello exstincto, re bene gesta, integro exercitu et praesidiis… eas vobis habeo grates atque ago. (Pl. *Per.* 753-756)

NB: although I'm basically looking for AA constructions that contain different juxtaposed (or coordinated) predications like the example above, those cases that involve, for example, long subordinated clauses depending on a single AA or many circumstantial adjuncts modifying it are also welcome!